How to make Claude API stop after producing certain special words?
I have some words that I do not want produced by Claude. No matter how I prompt it, there is a non zero chance that it will still get produced in the output. So I want to make it stop when it produces such a word instead of wastefully producing long sequences which I will filter out anyway and wasting money. Is there a way to do this?
I have a basic prompt like this so far
payload = {
    "prompt": "Tell me a 500 word joke but make sure it doesn't include the word 'blood' ",
    "model": "claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620",
    "max_tokens_to_sample": 50
}

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {API_KEY}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

response = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, json=payload, headers=headers)

I tried running it with the prompt but I notice that sometimes the word 'blood' still gets produced in 500 word jokes which I have to trim or ignore so it's a waste of resources.

See “stop_sequences” in the API. But I don’t know for sure if it will reduce your resource costs by a lot. Better to use strong prompting and maybe even fine tuning.
https://docs.anthropic.com/en/api/complete
stop_sequences
string[]
Sequences that will cause the model to stop generating.
Our models stop on "\n\nHuman:", and may include additional built-in stop sequences in the future. By providing the stop_sequences parameter, you may include additional strings that will cause the model to stop generating.

The cost is directly proportional to how many tokens are produced, so I think it should come down with this. thanks for the answer
